# Error With c Macro expansion

Tags: c++, macros

Hi please find the below simple macro code

```
#include <iostream>

#define INCL    #include

INCL <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, world\n" << std::endl ;

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile the code It throws 
error: stray â#â in program

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Preprocessor macros cannot create other preprocessor macros. You're just out of luck in this regard.

However, you *can* use a macro as the include argument:

```
#define FOO(x) "/usr/lib/" #x
#include FOO(mylib.h)
```

Comment: Hey Thanks, I want to mention here same code was fine on intel compiler. However we moved code from intel compiler to GCC compiler and we facing above mentioned Error.

I could not find any document mentioning that # can not be used at the start of macro. However I found documents mentioning '##' can not be used at the start or at the end

Answer (score 0):

C++ build consists of the following stages:

1. Preprocessing (macros expansion)
2. Compiling
3. Linking

The point is that you try to use preprocessor (stage 1) to preprocess itself, which won't work. The macros can only be used for generating the code for compiler. You cannot wrap a preprocessor directive into a preprocessor macro.